# Printing the hexadecimal value of assembly registers, moving 16 bit registers into 8 bit ones and other assembly questions

Tags: assembly, operating-system, cpu-registers, 16-bit, real-mode

I'm writing a function to print each register in my 16-bit real mode assembly operating system. I've come across a few problems:

1 Moving a 16-bit register into an 8-bit one

```
mov al, bx
```

This gives me `error: invalid combinations of opcodes and operands`. Is there anyway that I could do this?

2 Does moving a value into `ax` affect `ah` and/or `al`?

```
mov ah, 0x5
mov al, 0x10
mov ax, 0x20
```

Will `ah` still hold 0x5 and `al` hold 0x10?

3 Printing the hexadecimal value of a register and not the ascii code?

```
mov ah, 0x0e
mov al, 0x4d
int 0x10
```

This outputs the character 'm' and not 0x4d nor 77 nor 1001101 etc. Is the only option to convert 4d to 0x34 and 0x64 and then print?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Since 16 bits don't fit into 8 bits, you can't do that. Use the appropriate 8 bit register, such as `mov al, bl`. Going the other way, you can use `movzx` or `movsx` to zero- or sign-extend.
2. Yes, `AL` and `AH` are the two halves of `AX` (similarly for other registers, and further extended to 32 and 64 bit registers).
3. You need to convert, yes.